# How do I convert column of unix epoch to Date in Apache spark DataFrame using Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json data file which contain one property [creationDate] which is unix epoc in "long" number type. The Apache Spark DataFrame schema look like below:

```
root 
 |-- creationDate: long (nullable = true) 
 |-- id: long (nullable = true) 
 |-- postTypeId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- viewCount: long (nullable = true)
```

I would like to do some groupBy "creationData_Year" which need to get from "creationDate".

What's the easiest way to do this kind of convert in *DataFrame* using Java?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After checking spark dataframe api and sql function, I come out below snippet:

```
DateFrame df = sqlContext.read().json("MY_JSON_DATA_FILE");

DataFrame df_DateConverted = df.withColumn("creationDt", from_unixtime(df.col("creationDate").divide(1000)));
```

The reason why "creationDate" column is divided by "1000" is cause the TimeUnit is different. The orgin "creationDate" is unix epoch in "*milli-second*", however spark sql "**from_unixtime**" is designed to handle unix epoch in "*second*".

Comment: Your original issue was regarding the "group-by" granularity of long creationDate ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to group-by "Year" & "Month" of "creationDate", then do some aggregation.

Comment: So what was wrong with grouping by original creationDate column?

Comment: Because the origin data type in JSON is "long" (unix epoc) , I need to convert this field to "Year" and "Month", for example: 1452066042000 need to convert to "2016" for "createDate_Year" column and "1" for "createDate_Month" column. This way,  I can utilize spark df.groupBy() and some other aggregation function to computing.

Answer (score 8):

pyspark converts from Unix epoch milliseconds to dataframe timestamp

```
df.select(from_unixtime((df.my_date_column.cast('bigint')/1000)).cast('timestamp').alias('my_date_column'))
```

Answer (score 5):

In spark scala,

```
spark.sql("select from_unixtime(1593543333062/1000) as ts").show(false)
```