# Converting Epoch Seconds to timestamp using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark

I have a dataset like below:

```
+---+----------+
|id |t_date    |
+---+----------+
|1  |1635234395|
|1  |1635233361|
+---+----------+
```

Where `t_date` consists of `epoch` seconds of today's date. Now, I want to convert it to timestamp. I tried the below code but it is giving the wrong output:
[image]

I referred to the below two links but had no luck:

1. [How do I convert column of unix epoch to Date in Apache spark DataFrame using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626371/how-do-i-convert-column-of-unix-epoch-to-date-in-apache-spark-dataframe-using-ja)
2. [Converting epoch to datetime in PySpark data frame using udf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971903/converting-epoch-to-datetime-in-pyspark-data-frame-using-udf)

Comment: why do you divide by 1000 ? `from_unixtime` takes seconds as input, which you seem to already have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to divide it by `1000` , You can easily use `from_unixtime`

#### Data Preparation

```
input_str = """
1,1635234395,
1,1635233361
""".split(",")

input_values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, input_str))

cols = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, "id,t_date".split(',')))
            
n = len(input_values)

n_col = 2

input_list = [tuple(input_values[i:i+n_col]) for i in range(0,n,n_col)]

input_list

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list, cols)

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('t_date',F.col('t_date').cast('long'))

sparkDF.show()

+---+----------+
| id|    t_date|
+---+----------+
|  1|1635234395|
|  1|1635233361|
+---+----------+
```

#### From Unix Time

```
sparkDF.withColumn('t_date_parsed',F.from_unixtime(F.col('t_date'))).show()

+---+----------+-------------------+
| id|    t_date|      t_date_parsed|
+---+----------+-------------------+
|  1|1635234395|2021-10-26 13:16:35|
|  1|1635233361|2021-10-26 12:59:21|
+---+----------+-------------------+
```